# HTTPS connection using kafka-connect-http

Tags: apache-kafka, https, yaml

We are using kafka-connect-http and we are trying to set up an HTTPS (secure) connection but we are getting a the following error:
`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

We have CA certificates installed in the host and the following connector configuration YAML:

```
name: Connector_name
config:
connector.class: com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.HttpSourceConnector
tasks.max: 1
http.request.method: GET
http.request.url: https://example.com
http.request.headers: 'Content-Type: application/json'
http.auth.type: Basic
http.auth.user: user
http.auth.password: password
http.timer.interval.millis: 30000
http.timer.catchup.interval.millis: 1000
kafka.topic: topicname
```

We were expecting that the Kafka clusters would handle the certification process automatically as they all have a CA certificate in the host.

Another option would be to provide additional commands but we are not aware of which ones would be required.

Could anyone support us understand what additional information is required to set up a secure HTTPS connection?

Thank you in advance!